# PHP Force Download File Name with Spaces

Tags: php, force-download

Ok I seem to be having an issue with making my script download the file with the proper file name.

If I strip spaces and dashes which looks like this

```
if($type == 'mc'){
    $file_name = $_POST['Ids'];
    $file_name = str_replace('-', '', $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace(' ', '&amp;', $file_name);
    $url = base64_decode($stream);
    $file_url = "scd.php?stream=".$url."&name=".$file_name."";
    $url = array('url' => $file_url);
    echo json_encode($url);
}
```

Here is `scd.php`

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['stream'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
header("Content-type: application/x-file-to-save");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name.".mp3");
readfile($file);
exit();
?>
```

It will force the download but it will only save the first word in the name that is sent. So say the name is `Your Song Here` it wants to save it as `Your.mp3` but if I remove the `str_replace` from the `$file_name` variable then it will try to save the file as `Your` with no extension but still only the first word.

I need it to pass the entire `$file_name` variable ex. `Your Song Here.mp3` and still save it as an MP3 file.

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap the filename in quotes, something like

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"${name}.mp3\"");
```

(can't remember how to escape "s in a string in php).

I believe this is actually required by the HTTP specification.

Comment: Works like a charm, I will accept as the answer as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use an HTML entity (`&amp;`) in your file name. Don't do that. Also, don't use spaces in file names. You're better off replacing `' '` with `_`:

```
$file_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $file_name);
```

Then your file name will be safe to pass to via url without any special encoding or escaping needed.